# Can apache ignite's shared RDD works in embedded mode

Tags: ignite

I really love the Apache Ignite's shared RDD for spark. However, due to the limitation, I can not deploy ignite onto cluster nodes. The only way I can use Ignite is throuhgh embedded mode with Spark.

I would like to knowledge, in embedded mode, can the RDD shared through different Spark applications?

I have two Spark jobs:

Job 1: Produce the data, and stores into the shared RDD
Job 2: retrieve the data from the Shared RDD, and do some calculation.

Can this task be done using ignite's embedded mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In embedded mode Ignite nodes are started within executors which are under control of Spark. Having said that, this mode is more for testing purposes in my opinion - no need to deploy and start Ignite separately while having an ability to try basic functionality. But in real scenarios it would be very hard to achieve consistency and failover guarantees as Spark can start and stop executors which in case of embedded mode are actually holding the data. I would recommend to work around your limitation and make sure Ignite can be installed separately in standalone mode.